# Netlogo Behaviorspace issue--Access Denied or Failure to Write to Disk

Tags: netlogo, behaviorspace

I am attempting to run a behaviorspace model in Netlogo (Version 6.2.2). When I click run it asks me where to save and what to name the file. I use the defaults--exporting as a spreadsheet (the current working directory is where the model is saved in my dropbox). It then runs the model, but when I look in the designated folder nothing is there? And when I search my entire hard drive the file can't be located anywhere. Even stranger, when I went to re-run it, it seemed to have re-set the working directory to the program folder for the netlogo app?
I tried restarting the program, and then I got the following error: "Experiment aborted due to file input or output (I/O) error: .\E (Access is denied)"
However, I am running as an administrator and I double-checked that Netlogo has permission to read and write, so I don't know why it thinks it doesn't have permission? At this point I've tried restarting the program, re-saving the model under a different name, uninstalling completely and reinstalling, manually ensuring I am running as an administrator, and nothing has worked! I am completely at a loss, and any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I am running Windows 10, 64 bit.

EDIT: It seems as if the issue is actually with dropbox. I have no issue writing the behaviorspace to folders outside of dropbox

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot help you with Dropbox but writing output there instead of to your own hard disk does not seem like a good idea.

But: Be aware that the "Table" output is almost always better than "Spreadsheet". The Spreadsheet format is harder to do statistics on and can, for big model runs, use up huge amounts of your computer's memory (it saves a lot of data in memory instead of just writing it to the file, which Table format does). You might best do a very small experiment using each format and decide which you like.

Comment: Thanks! I think the problem might be that dropbox was updating in the background while the model was running. I've never run into trouble with it before and today it seems to be working again! I guess I will just leave this as a warning for anyone else running a behaviorspace model saving into a dropbox folder!